# How can I block OS X's Apple App store by edit hosts file?

Tags: macos, hosts

I know I can easily block Google.HK just to add those lines in hosts

```
0.0.0.0 www.google.com.hk
        www.google.com.hk
```

But can I use hosts file to block certain App? Like what if I want to block Apple App Store, and can I do that by editing hosts file?

Comment: You need www.facebook.com to block facebook ...

Comment: Have you tried blocking itunes.apple.com? (the app store is https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios/id36?mt=8)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Apple has ever released their IP addresses, so you couldn't block a range. I'd start with these for the itunes store -

```
* itunes.apple.com
* ax.itunes.apple.com
* albert.apple.com
* gs.apple.com
```

[Apple KB](http://support.apple.com/en-us/TS1379)

If that fails, maybe check [this answer over at](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54097/cant-access-apple-com-webservers-app-store-nor-software-update) apple.SE.